# Install npm serve package locally

Tags: node.js, npm-install, local, executable

All the installation document of the npm serve package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) say to install it globally:

`npm install --global serve`

However, on a remove server that I don't have sudo/root access, it is still possible to install it locally and use it locally?

I did, but I didn't find the normally `bin` folder (or executables) that I used to see, just as other tools like `eslint`, `typescript` etc...